# Sum of squares on GPU

Tags: code-golf

Write a program or function that:

1. Takes as input a list or array of 128 numbers.
2. Sends that array to a GPU
3. Performs a calculation on the GPU to square each element of the array and then sum them
4. Gets the answer from the GPU, and returns or displays it

So your program will simply return the sum of the squares of its input array, but it will perform the calculation on a GPU.

The input numbers should be sent to the GPU in the form of signed or unsigned integer types or floats, of 32 or more bits in size.

You may make any assumptions you like about hardware, e.g. you may assume a CUDA or OpenCl capable card is present without checking for it.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The smallest code (in bytes) will be considered the winner for each language.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14709/21034) (deleted)

Comment: that would be +/×⍨ in apl with https://github.com/Co-dfns/Co-dfns :)

Comment: @ngn I'm curious why you didn't post that as an answer - is there a reason?

Comment: it would take me a long time to apply for a dyalog licence, install a recent version of dyalog, then download and compile co-dfns, and make sure it works on my 10-year-old laptop

Comment: ...and there's always danger that the co-dfns compiler might decide that using the gpu is not worth it for arrays of size <1000000 :) - I haven't been following the trends there for a while

Comment: @ngn Your 10-year-old laptop has a discreet GPU?

Comment: @Adám it looks like it's integrated, lspci shows: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Comment: The sum of the squares of 128 32-bit integers may very well overflow the 32-bit integer type. May we assume it won't?

Comment: @Adám yes, you may assume that.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/) with [Co-dfns](https://github.com/Co-dfns/Co-dfns), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous prefix lambda. I have verified with [the author of Co-dfns](https://www.patreon.com/arcfide) that the code will indeed run according to the required spec.

```apl
{+.×⍨⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO96FHbhHCuNCD5qLfvUVez0aO2yY/6pvoFqYerP@puedQ2CaTC4H@1tt7h6Y96Vzzq3VoL0scV/l/drzQ3KbWoWCGxKNVKnQuoC6gyDyIGZB1ab2JgaaZtb2hk8ah3i4WhpRGXenBprkJ@mkJxYSlQTzFQU5oCVAMA) (equivalent code, but TIO doesn't provide GPU access)

`{`…`}` compilable dfn; `⍵` is the argument vector

`+.×` dot-product of

`⍨` itself ("selfie")

`⍵` using the argument as data

Answer (score 2):

## Processing.org 392 bytes

392 counting the shader and function

It's possible to reduce the number of characters by putting the shader program in a separate file.

```
String[] f={"uniform float x[128];void main(){float s;for(int i=0;i<128;i++)s+=x[i]*x[i];int b=floatBitsToInt(s);gl_FragColor=vec4(b>>16&255,b>>8&255,b&255,b>>24&255)/255.;}"},v={"uniform mat4 transform;in vec4 vertex;void main(){gl_Position=transform*vertex;}"};PShader p;void s(float[]i){p=new PShader(this,v,f);p.set("x",i,1);filter(p);loadPixels();print(Float.intBitsToFloat(pixels[0]));}
void setup(){
size(1,1,P2D);
float[] input = new float[128];
for(int i=0;i<128;i++)input[i]=(float)i;
s(input); // prints 690880.0
}
```